# how does the program gets loaded in memory when you have several memory region?

Tags: c, memory, linker, bootloader, firmware

Let's say I have SOC that have different processors (embedded SOC) and different memory regions. let's say it has internal ram for 3 different processors it has and an external ddr ram, let's call them sram1,sram2,sram3, and ddr1.
let's say I write some code and write a linker that uses all 4 different memories (and perhaps few sections per memory). I think what it means at this stage is that linker assumes your code is running at those addresses and resolves addresses based on them. But in order for this code to actually run, it has to be put in the correct addresses and then run. and I'm confused about this part, who makes sure that the code is copied into the right memory addresses before it's run ? is it the initial software that is running ?

In my case, the initial code (bootloader) is loaded by ROM. the ROM looks for an address in a specidfied format (specific to my processors) and copies the code from boot media (sd card) there. which is all the code in one region (let's say sram1). this makes sense, few hundred KBs of bootloader code gets copied in one of the regions which matches the linker file. What confuses me is after this : let's say my bootloader wants to load another app, and as I mentioned, that app uses all 4 different memory regions. is it the duty of bootloader to make sure the code is copied from sd card to the correct memory regions before passing control to it ? I think it should be, but then the bootloader should completely know how you have linked your app with the linker script, and I think this doesn't make sense. Can you enlighten me of how it works ?

Comment: memory layout has to be  stored in the executable file you load. Using this information you can load the partular chunks of the file into the correct memory areas. Mode complicated exutable formats may include much more information - for example relocation tables, GOT and many more. It is a huge topic and you will not be able to learn it asking questions on Q&A portals.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing some more details. What SOC is this? Could you provide a [mre], with emphasis on "complete" and "minimal", please? A URL to the documentation of the SOC and its bootloader will help us to have some insight.